# Java Hibernate Criteria. Select by the subclass property from subclass list

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three `Java` `hibernate` entities. And I want using `hibernate criteria` get all Users who has pick with specific id in their picks list.

Users entity:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="users")
  public class User {
      ...
      @ManyToMany
      private List<UserPick> picks = new ArrayList<UserPick>(0);
      ...
```

UserPick entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usersPicks")
public class UserPick {
...
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user") 
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  private MatchPick pick;
  ...
```

I want get all of the users that have pick with specific pick.id, like:

```
// return all users if exist pick with pickId in picks list
public List<User> getUsersByPick(int pickId) {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria... //
    return criteria.list();
}

// Goal is get target but using Hibernate criteries
public List<User> getUsersByPick(int pickId) {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    List<User> users = criteria.list();
    List<User> target = new List<>();

    for(User u:users)
       for(UserPick p:u.getPicks())
         if(p.getId == pickId)target.add(u);

    return target;
}
```

Comment: I want get all users from database who have e.g pick with id 2.

Comment: We know it. But what have you tried? This is not a get Code for free platform.

Comment: I tried read something about alias, but I need to know or it is right direction

Comment: aliasses are the right firection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work for me.

```
   public List<User> getUsersByPick(int pickId) {
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class)
        .createCriteria("userPicks", "picks")
        .createCriteria("pick", "pick")
        .add( Restrictions.eq("pick.id",pickId) );
        return criteria.list();
    }
```